# Can someone please explain clearly how to use "pngcrush" for multiply items

Tags: terminal, png, pngcrush

I have a stack of hundreds of pictures and i want to use pngcrush for reducing the file sizes.

I know how to crush one file with terminal, but all over the web i find parts of explanations that assume previous knowledge.

can someone please explain how to do it clearly.

Thanks
Shani

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use following script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# uncomment following line for more aggressive but longer compression
# pngcrush_options=-reduce -brute -l9
find . -name '*.png' -print | while read f; do
  pngcrush $pngcrush_options -e '.pngcrushed' "$f"
  mv "$f" "${f/%.pngcrushed/}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Current versions of pngcrush support this functionality out of the box.

( I am using pngcrush 1.7.81)

`pngcrush -dir outputFolder inputFolder/*.png`

will create "outputFolder" if it does not exist and process all the .png files in the "inputFolder" placing them in "outputFolder".

Obviously you can add other options e.g.

`pngcrush -dir outputFolder -reduce -brute -l9 inputFolder/*.png`

Answer (score 0):

Being in 2023, there are better tools to optimize png images like **OptiPNG**

1. - install

```
sudo apt-get install optipng
```

2. - use for one picture

```
optipng imagen.png
```

3. - use for all pictures in folder

```
find /path/to/files/ -name '*.png' -exec optipng -o7 {} \;
```

optionally the command -o defines the quality, being possible from 1 to 7, where 7 is the maximum compression level of the image.

```
-o7
```

Answer (score -1):

The high rated fix appears dangerous to me; it started compressing all png files in my iMac; needed is a command restricted to a specified directory; I am no UNIX expert; I undid the new files by searching for all files ending in `.pngcrushed` and deleting them